# Check if at least two hours have been spent within a time range, when given two dates

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I have two dates and I need to check if at least 2 consecutive hours have been spent between the times 1AM and 5AM, within those dates.

For example, if dateFrom is 2014-05-05 17:00:00 and dateTo is 2014-05-06 6:00:00, this means that 2 consecutive hours have been spend between 1AM and 5AM between those two dates.

The times (1AM and 5AM) are to be configurable and not hard-coded - thus, represented as variables.

This is what I have done so far:

```
//The timeFromResidencyRange and timeToResidencyRange are 1AM and 5AM respectively.  
//They are collected from two `DateTimePicker` .NET controls.

timeFromResidencyRange = dtpTime1.Value; //For testing, it is 1AM (but can be any time)
timeToResidencyRange = dtpTime2.Value; //For testing, it is 5AM (but can be any time)

private bool IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, double consecutiveHours)
{
    var totalDiff = (dateTo - dateFrom).TotalHours;

    if (totalDiff < consecutiveHours)
    {
        return false;
    }

    DateTime desireFromDate = new DateTime();

    if ((dateFrom.TimeOfDay.Hours < timeToResidencyRange.Hour) || (dateFrom.TimeOfDay.Hours == timeToResidencyRange.Hour && dateFrom.TimeOfDay.Minutes == timeToResidencyRange.Minute && dateFrom.TimeOfDay.Seconds == 0))
    {
        desireFromDate = dateFrom;
    }
    else
    {
        desireFromDate = dateFrom.AddDays(1);
    }

    var endOfDesireDate = new DateTime(desireFromDate.Year,
                                       desireFromDate.Month,
                                       desireFromDate.Day, timeToResidencyRange.Hour, timeToResidencyRange.Minute, 0);

    if ((endOfDesireDate - dateFrom).TotalHours < consecutiveHours)
    {
        endOfDesireDate = endOfDesireDate.AddDays(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }

    desireFromDate = endOfDesireDate.AddHours(-((timeToResidencyRange - timeFromResidencyRange).TotalHours));

    return (dateTo - desireFromDate).TotalHours >= consecutiveHours;
}
```

As test cases, I have carried out the following:

```
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 1:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 5:00:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //true
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 2:30:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 5:00:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //true
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 1:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-06 17:00:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //true
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 15:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 1:59:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //false
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 15:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 2:59:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //false
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 15:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-06 3:00:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //true
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("26/08/2013 17:17:13"), DateTime.Parse("26/08/2013 20:20:30"), (double)amountOfHours); //false
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("26/08/2013 17:17:13"), DateTime.Parse("29/08/2013 20:20:30"), (double)amountOfHours); //true
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-04 1:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-06 5:00:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //true
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 1:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-15 5:00:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //true
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 1:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-06-05 5:00:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //true
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 3:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 5:00:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //true
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 3:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 4:59:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //false
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 1:25:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 2:25:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //false
IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 1:25:00"), DateTime.Parse("2014-05-05 3:25:00"), (double)amountOfHours); //true
```

The comments to the right are what the expected outcome should be - Within this set, the 6th one is failing, but I suspect that the others are working as a coincidence - as otherwise they would all work, or all fail.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing it?

Comment: Which of your tests are failing?

Comment: Within that set, the 6th one is failing, but I suspect that the others are working as a coincidence - as otherwise they would all work, or all fail.

Comment: Could you please add the declaration of the 1AM and 5AM variables?

Comment: What is `timeToResidencyRange`? If you could add some comments to your code explaining the logic that might help us a bit

Comment: You are both right - sorry about that. Editing it now.

Comment: Say the interval is from 12/5 00:00 to 14/5 14:00, what should be the date of the "Residency Range"?

Comment: The user has two DateTimePickers - one for the "From" and "To", where he can only select the time.  He can thus select 1AM and 5AM. On doing so, the whole DateTime value would be today's date at the time selected by the user

Comment: Yes, but in your example code you are running this against dates which are not anywhere near today's date. So, if you pass an interval where the span selected by the user can be seen multiple times, which interval do you choose to compare against?

Comment: Actually I have tested it and the DateTimePickers actually do not seem to be using today's date.  They are `{03/12/2014 01:00:53}` and `{03/12/2014 05:00:53` respectively. Not sure why exactly - but I suspect 3rd December is the day when I added the DateTime picker, so as a default date, it must be using that. To combat this problem, in my code I have extracted the Hour and Minute values, rather than the whole date.

Comment: The `Value` of the DateTimePicker is most likely already set, and then when the user changes the value, they can only change the Time of this. Nevertheless you need to be a bit more specific in explaining your logic behind which dates the span should choose.

Comment: Kindly note my comment edit above

Comment: @Sander - Regarding which dates the span can choose, at this stage I am testing it on those dates which I have mentioned in my test cases. They can be any two dates imaginable, as long as they occur as a range.

Comment: Ok. But you still haven't stated how the date should be chosen? If the date spans from the 5th to the 6th, which span (1-5AM in this case) should it choose?

Comment: Are you referring to the dateFrom and dateTo? These are taken from a database of date pairs, and I am checking to see if between each pair there is at least X consecutive hours between time Y and Z. The dateFrom and dateTo can be any values, even a week apart for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about this problem I think it can be solved with a lot less logic. Having doodled a bit and thought about it I would adress this problem as follows;

**EDIT**: Updated code to check all possible ranges in the dates of the GIVEN range.
**EDIT2**: Now returns number of occurances in the given range.

```
private int IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, double consecutiveHours){

    var dates = new List<DateTime>();
    for (var date = dateFrom.Date; date <= dateTo; date = date.AddDays(1))
        dates.Add(date);

    var occurances = 0;
    foreach (var testDate in dates)
    {
        var testFrom = new DateTime(testDate.Year, testDate.Month, testDate.Day, timeFromResidencyRange.TimeOfDay.Hours, timeFromResidencyRange.TimeOfDay.Minutes,0);
        var testTo = new DateTime(testDate.Year, testDate.Month, testDate.Day, timeToResidencyRange.TimeOfDay.Hours, timeToResidencyRange.TimeOfDay.Minutes, 0);

        if (WithinFrame(dateFrom, dateTo, consecutiveHours, testFrom, testTo))
            occurances++;
    }
    return occurances;

}

private bool WithinFrame(DateTime from, DateTime to, double consecutiveHours, DateTime rangeFrom, DateTime rangeTo)
{
    if (from < rangeFrom)
    {
        return ((to - rangeFrom).TotalHours >= consecutiveHours);
    }
    else if (to > rangeTo)
    {
        return ((rangeTo - from).TotalHours >= consecutiveHours);
    }
    else
    {
        //Is completely within range.
        return ((to - from).TotalHours >= consecutiveHours);
    }
}
```

This will basically check to see whether the dates that are entered overlap the "wanted range". If the set date starts before 1AM, it check to see that there is atleast two hours (or whatever value you specify) from the wanted start to the given end date.

And if it doesn't start before but ends after 5AM, it checks that it atleast has two hours from the given start to the wanted end.

If it is within the range, check to see that the total difference in hours is greater than 2 (or whatever is given).

Hope this explanation is clear enough :)

Comment: Thanks for the information and code - I will test it with some cases,and let you know what the outcome is :) Logically, it is more or less what I came up with, but in a much more concise manner!

Comment: I had trouble with #7 and #8 when parsing, but I think that is a local format configuration. Let me know if it works!

Comment: I just tried all the above cases - unfortunately the function returned false for everything.

Comment: Since the timeFromResidencyRange and timeToResidencyRange are taken from a DateTimePicker which only displays the time to the user, the actual DateTime value of each one is displayed as today's date, with 1AM and today's date with 5AM.  Thus, it looks like the first if-statement is always being entered.  I suspect that is the issue.

Comment: Probably, in my example I simply set the value to be "2014-05-05 1AM" and "2014-05-05 5AM". If it is to be computed which day it is going to be, then it would require more code and logic (for instance if the date span is over two days, which would it choose for the 1-5AM interval).

Comment: Hence my more complex code :) However I am still unsure of where my problem lies

Comment: Changed my solution, now checks all intervals on all dates within the given range.

Comment: Thanks :) I shall be testing it and will let you know if it works!

Comment: I am in the process of testing it, however there are some instances where more than one range exist within a set of dates. For example, if there are two dates which have 5 days between them, I would like to return the amount of times the date range contains the time range - i.e. how many times it satisfies the requirement of having the 1AM-5AM range inside. Is it possible to modify your code to return this number instead?

Comment: Changed so now it returns number of occurances.

Comment: Thanks Sander - I'm still testing and unfortunately have come across a case which does not work. When given a dateFrom of 2013-08-14 22:10:49 and dateTo of 2013-08-15 00:27:32, it is returning true, when it should be returning false.

Comment: Updated code, it was comparing hours of days (even when days where on different days).

Comment: As far as I have tested it works. Might need some minor tweaks (if I have missed something), but I think you can get there yourself. :) If you think that this is correct, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, free of syntax, what is the truth:

```
A: Period Begin 1AM;
B: Period End   5AM;
a-b range between a Date1 and b Date2
```

For two consecutive hours within (A-B) then:

```
if
 (
  (
   a <= B - 2h
   OR
   b >= A + 2h
  )
  AND
  (b-a) >= 2h
 )
 bool = true
 else
 bool = false
```

Can you test this please?

```
    DateTime A = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 01:00:00");
    DateTime B = DateTime.Parse("1900-01-01 05:00:00");
    int amountOfHours = 2;

public bool IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime a, DateTime b, double c)
{
if ((b - a).TotalHours >= c 
&& (a.TimeOfDay.Hours <= this.B.TimeOfDay.Hours - c 
||  b.TimeOfDay.Hours >= this.A.TimeOfDay.Hours + c))
{
return true;
}
//else
return false;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code, and it is failing on the following tests:

`IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2013-08-26 17:17:13"), DateTime.Parse("2013-08-26 20:20:30"), (double)amountOfHours); //false`

and 

`IsWithinResidencyRange(DateTime.Parse("2013-08-26 17:17:13"), DateTime.Parse("2013-08-29 20:20:30"), (double)amountOfHours); //true`

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this formatting is invalid. Mine fails for them too. Ignoring those two lines, I get the expected results... I think :)

Comment: Well-worked out answer! Good to see someone thinking about the logic instead of just churning out the code.